# What is the right way using the build context outside the build function

Tags: flutter

Lets say I'm enter my named route page and get the arguments in the build function.
Now my widget is state full widget and i want to make api call with the arguments in order to set the state of my widget.
I'm using future Builder to load the api when the page is loading, so i have to create Future and equal him to the api func right?
but i cant do it inside the build it will call it unlimited times, so  i send it as props to an other widget but really i should create widget just in order to send my context values?

```
class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  GameScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  Fixture fixture;

  Future setFIxture(externalId) async {
    final response =
        await FixturesService().getLiveFixtureByExternalId(externalId);
    setState(() {
      fixture = response;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GameScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    Future initScreen;

    initScreen = setFIxture(args.externald);

    return RoutePage(
      child: Loader(
        future: initScreen,
        succeed: Container(
          height: 223,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(""),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(""),
                      Text(""),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      // TeamImage(),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(""),
                          Text(""),
                        ],
                      ),
                      // TeamImage(),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(""),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my loader widget:

```
class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future future;
  final Widget succeed;

  Loader({Key key, this.future, this.succeed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState();
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> {
  Future _getTaskAsync;
  final spinkit = SpinKitFadingCircle(
    color: Colors.black,
    size: 40,
  );

  Future fetchData() async {
    try {
      await widget.future;
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getTaskAsync = fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getTaskAsync,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return widget.succeed;
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("error");
        } else {
          return spinkit;
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use streamProvider from the provider package.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to create another widget. But maybe use a dependency injection solution to make it simpler to inject objects into the widget tree (Riverpod is good i heard). Store the GameScreen args inside a shared state above in the widget tree.

Comment: It is like provider no? shared state is for situations i want to use the state in many widgets using this for this situation is right?

Comment: Yes generally speaking - if you want to access something in a part of a widget tree for many widgets above - you must have a shared state somehow. If it is Riverpod, Provider, Inherited Widget or any other method is up to you